# Querying a SQL Table with over 10million rows

Tags: python, sql, performance, pyodbc, dremio

I have a table with over 10 million rows in Dremio. I have connected to it from  Python PYODBC. I want to run a simple query like shown below:

```
SELECT REPORTDATE, TRANSDATE 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE TRANSDATE = '2020-01-05'
```

The issue is that it takes forever to run this query via Python.
What would be the solution for this?

Comment: Make sure there's an index on the `TRANSDATE` column. Otherwise it has to read every row.

Comment: @Barmar thanks a lot for your reply. Can you tell me how to do that? Does this mean that I have to add a new index column into the table?

Comment: I don't know Dremio, but in normal SQL it's `ALTER TABLE tablename ADD INDEX (transdate)`

Comment: @Barmar But to do that the field "TRANSDATE" should be unique, right?

Comment: No. If you want to declare it unique you use `ADD UNIQUE INDEX`

Comment: Perfect! If possible, can you explain to me what exactly happens when I add this new index? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Any database textbook or tutorial should explain what indexes do. This is a fundamental DBMS concept.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using sqlalchemy or pandas to make the call. 
Personally, I use pandas (below example uses cx_Oracle since we use Oracle servers):

```
import pandas as pd

qry = '''
SELECT REPORTDATE, TRANSDATE 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE TRANSDATE = '2020-01-05'
'''

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('host-name','port',service_name='database')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=user_name, password=pwd, dsn=dsn_tns)
c = conn.cursor()
results = pd.read_sql(qry , conn)
c.close()
conn.close()
```

If it still runs too slow, you can pull it in chunks using the `chunksize` attribute: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Oracle's [python-oracledb driver](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/) instead of pyodbc and increase the `arraysize` value, see https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance

```
cur = connection.cursor()

cur.arraysize = 5000

for row in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM very_big_table"):
    print(row)
```

Unless you actually want a Pandas data frame, using the driver native calls will be fastest.

The 'Thin' mode (which is the default) of python-oracledb is likely to be faster than the 'Thick' mode.